# Gui - How to give process information to user?

Tags: swing, user-interface

How can I inform the users like the works which the program does in that moment ? Is there any changeable text element or something like that, so I can update it ?

For example:

```
The 1st song is finished.
```

Then it disappears and:

```
The 2nd song is finished.
```

Comment: Just use a `JLabel`.

Comment: Any component based on a `JTextComponent` or a `JLabel` would do